# How to properly save data inside multiple fragment with one click?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, save

**Intro**

Hi guys. Currently I am working on a question-form app. Adding an item in the MainActivity opens a QuestionListActivity. Clicking on the first item opens the Main2Activity which contains 3 fragments (tabbed with Viewpager). Each fragment contains an EditText field to answer the question in. And a Toolbar with a save button. The first question is to give the form a name which is viewable in the MainActivity. Clicking on one of the saved items in the MainActivity opens the QuestionList and then clicking on the first item shows the fragments with their saved data already in the EditText form to view or change. After working in these fragments the save button should save all the fragments at once instead of one at a time.

**Problem**

First I was able to only save the items. But it wasn't possible to view them. Then I fixed my java classes for each fragment and now it is possible to view all the saved data inside the fragments for each saved item in the MainActivity. But now the problem is that I can't save new data, or change my already saved data, because then I get a null object reference in my private void saveNote part of my code (LogCat).

**Question**

I obviously shouldn't call title, question2 and question3 in my oncreate method in my Main2Activity, hence this causes the null object reference. But I really don't know how to do this the right way. Hopefully someone knows how to save the data from each fragment inside one item the right way and maybe how to change title, question2 and question3 inside the private void saveNote.

(I searched on StackOverFlow for the right answer, but unfortunately I this wasn't able to help me in this particular way)

**Codes**

Right here I post the codes of my Main2Activity and one fragment (Frag1). The other fragments are setup in the same way.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private void saveNote() {

    String title1,title2,title3;
    for(int position = 0; position<mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();position++){
        Fragment fragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
        if(fragment instanceof Frag1){
            title1 = ((Frag1)fragment).getTitle();
        } else  if(fragment instanceof Frag2){
            title2 = ((Frag2)fragment).getQuestion2();
        } else  if(fragment instanceof Frag3){
            title3 = ((Frag3)fragment).getQuestion3();
        }
    }

    boolean valid = !TextUtils.isEmpty(title1);
    valid = valid && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title2);
    valid = valid && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title3);

    Note note;

    if(!valid()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    note = new Note((mLoadedNote != null)?mLoadedNote.getDateTime():System.currentTimeMillis(), title.getText().toString(), question2.getText().toString(), question3.getText().toString());

    if (Utilities.saveNote(this, note)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "not enough space", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    finish();
}
```

```
08-23 13:53:52.045 7779-7779/com.example.beginnoteinidee E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.beginnoteinidee, PID: 7779
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.beginnoteinidee.Main2Activity.saveNote(Main2Activity.java:109)
    at com.example.beginnoteinidee.Main2Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(Main2Activity.java:139)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:64)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:204)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Code looks good, where you exactly getting NPE ? share the log if you have

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Looks like some of views are null , can you please add log after question3 to see whether all views are null or not null. also share the **activity_main2.xml**

Comment: Well I already know that these views are null. As I said under PROBLEM, I call them by their id inside the fragment layout. Example: title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_et_title1); is inside the layout of Frag1 instead of Main2Activity. Theirfore I know why I get the null object reference error but I don't know how to fix this. Should I call the saveNote method in the java class for each fragment seperately? And how can I make it possible to save all the fragments by one click instead of one by one

Comment: share the **activity_main2.xml** layout file. FYI, in your `activity_main2.xml` there must be three editText with id `note_et_title1, note_et_title2, and note_et_title3`

Comment: As I said, these are inside my fragment layouts. Therefore I know this isn't working. But I don't know how to do it the right way to get it how I want it

Comment: Thats fine, no worries. Can you please tell me where all these edittexts are defined note_et_title1, note_et_title2, and note_et_title3 ? I mean under which xml layout file

Comment: If those views are inside fragment you can't directly access them from your activity. Try using interfaces.

Comment: I added the layout of Frag1 (frag1_layout.xml)

Comment: But I can see there is only **note_et_title1** but where is other two note_et_title2 and note_et_title3 ?

Comment: These are inside frag2_layout and frag3_layout. Each question should have a different page. So they look exactly like frag1_layout except note_et_title2 is in frag2layout and note_et_title3 in frag 3 layout

Comment: Now I understood , you have three fragments under viewpager Frag1, Frag2 and Frag3.. and each fragment have one edittext, now you want to save on menu item clicked. correct ?

Comment: exactly! Sorry if I was unclear about that.

Comment: You should change the approach, for now we can fix this issue but later on in near future you may have some other issues. I would recommend you to change your design. If possible share the code base on github, because I need to make the changes on many files.

Comment: @pr0gram try the answer now, it should solve your issue

Comment: I think your new changes are the right way to go! Still got some minor issues before I can go and try this on the emulator. I changed my codes (editted them as well in my question codes) according to your suggestion but inside each fragment I get the Incompatible types error: required String, found text.editable and inside my Main2Activity. Besides, in my Main2Activity in the Boolean valid part you added, it says the variable titles might not have been initialized. And here it asks for a method call: if(!valid()){

Comment: Corrected now, you can try now

Comment: Still asks for a method call right here: if(!valid()){ , after this it should work

Comment: Correct now,  please check. it was typo error

Comment: Ofcourse I still get a null point reference at : note = new Ideas((mLoadedNote != null)?mLoadedNote.getDateTime():System.currentTimeMillis(), title.getText().toString(), question2.getText().toString(), question3.getText().toString()); ofcourse title, question2 and question3 still refer to nothing since they are not inside the Main2Activity layout. SHould I change them to title1 title2 and title3?

Comment: You didn't take the latest I gues, please use the same what I added in answer post.

Comment: My bad! you are right, lets check

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you very much for your time and patience, it worked!

Comment: @pr0gram Awesome !! Glad to know I could solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your saveNote method like below,

```
private void saveNote() {

    String title1="",title2="",title3="";
    for(int position = 0; position<mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();position++){
        Fragment fragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
        if(fragment instanceof Frag1){
            title1 = ((Frag1)fragment).getTitle();
        } else  if(fragment instanceof Frag2){
            title2 = ((Frag2)fragment).getTitle();
        } else  if(fragment instanceof Frag2){
            title3 = ((Frag2)fragment).getTitle();
        }
    }

    boolean valid = !TextUtils.isEmpty(title1);
    valid = valid && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title2);
    valid = valid && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title3);

    Note note;

    if(!valid){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    note = new Note((mLoadedNote != null)?mLoadedNote.getDateTime():System.currentTimeMillis(), title1, title2, title3);

    if (Utilities.saveNote(this, note)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "not enough space", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    finish();
}
```

You also need to create method getTitle on each fragment Frag1, Frag2 and Frag3.

For example,

**Frag1**

```
public String getTitle(){
 return mEtTitle.getText().toString();
}
```